# Parsing column of table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

i parse the table with this pattern code:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open("out.html"), 'html.parser')
tab = soup.findAll('table')[3] 
rows = tab.find_all('tr')

for sing_row in rows:
    col = sing_row.find_all('td')[1]
    print col
```

The result of print is:

```
<td class="col-md-3">5.67.43.158<br/><span style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #eee;"></span></td>
<td class="col-md-3">32.54.44.155<br/><span style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #eee;">ns2.asdf.it</span></td>
<td class="col-md-3">53.64.21.154<br/><span style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #eee;">server1.adb.it</span></td>
<td class="col-md-3">23.62.53.22<br/><span style="font-size: 0.9em; color: #eee;">server1.xcvf.it</span></td>
```

My goal is to get only the IP address from the table column without the domains inside the span. How can I proceed?

Comment: Try `sing_row.find_all('td')[1].contents`

Comment: Marcus, if the answer provided does what you want then you should mark it 'accepted'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `tag.contents`:

```
for sing_row in rows:
    col = sing_row.find_all('td')[1]
    print col.contents
```

---

You can also use `tag.find(text=True)`:

```
for sing_row in rows:
    col = sing_row.find_all('td')[1]
    print col.find(text=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.